# netbeans update center for XML tools

Tags: xml, netbeans

The update center of the XML module at

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/xml/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml

is no longer accessible at this time.

Is the XML module already included as part the core NetBeans product,
or the update center URL has moved to somewhere else, or...?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here. Searching for a download-location that still works. 

I have a working NB installation with working XML Tools, but I have no idea how to extract the XML Tools plugin to make it work in other NB installations.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently on Oct/2018 there is a backup on a Netbeans server

http://bits.netbeans.org/hudson/job/xml/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/updates/updates.xml

Comment: In NetBeans version 11.3, out of the box from the plugin center, there'd be a jdesktop.layout NBM missing. But if you google, download, and include that missing nbm, the plugin still works.

Comment: also note that jdesktop-layout NBM does not seem to work with jdk14 while jdk13 it is ok. in other words, netbeans 11.3 on jdk14 is a combo that no longer works with this xml tools plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Found this:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40292/xmltools4netbeans
Download the ZIP, extract it, and install each extracted NBM file.

Works even with latest Netbeans 9 Developer Preview.

Would love to see this XML Tools Project further continued and supported.